# I want to make the heading in centre instead of left

Tags: sectioning

I am writing thesis. But my uni requires Headings in Centre. I want to make the heading of my thesis in centre instead of left.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What do you call the *heading*? The header which appears at the top of each page?

Comment: I mean Chapter e.g. Chapter 1 Introductions. Not the header/footer.

Comment: Which class do you use?

Comment: \documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}

Comment: I just changed to 11pt for the example, as it looked better with this font. Choosing the 12pt option won't change the general layout (perhaps adapt the spacing parameters – it's up to you to check if it's fine as is or not). Also, I don't  think you'll use `garamondx` as your document font…

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do it with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsproc

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}%
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter\bfseries}
{{\huge\chaptername~\thechapter}}
{4ex}
{\Huge}%
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-8ex}{12ex}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{44}
 \chapter{My Chapter upon Chapters}

Is it not a shame to make two chapters of what passed in going down one pair of stairs? for we are got no farther yet than to the first landing,
and there are fifteen more steps down to the bottom; and for aught I know, as my father and my uncle Toby are in a talking humour, there may be as many chapters as steps:---let that be as it will, Sir, I can no more help it than my destiny:---A sudden impulse comes across me---drop the curtain, Shandy---I drop it---Strike a line here across the paper, Tristram---I strike it---and hey for a new chapter.

The deuce of any other rule have I to govern myself by in this affair---and if I had one---as I do all things out of all rule---I would
twist it and tear it to pieces, and throw it into the fire when I had done---Am I warm? I am, and the cause demands it---a pretty story! is a
man to follow rules---or rules to follow him?

Now this, you must know, being my chapter upon chapters, which I promised to write before I went to sleep, I thought it meet to ease my conscience entirely before I laid down, by telling the world all I knew about the matter at once: Is not this ten times better than to set out dogmatically with a sententious parade of wisdom, and telling the world a story of a roasted horse---that chapters relieve the mind---that they assist---or impose upon the imagination---and that in a work of this dramatic cast they are as necessary as the shifting of scenes---with fifty other cold conceits, enough to extinguish the fire which roasted him?---O! but to understand this, which is a puff at the fire of Diana's temple---you must read Longinus---read away---if you are not a jot the wiser by reading him the first time over---never fear---read him again---Avicenna and Licetus read Aristotle's metaphysicks forty times through a-piece, and never understood a single word.---But mark the consequence---Avicenna turned out a desperate writer at all kinds of writing---for he wrote books \emph{de omni scribili}; and for Licetus (Fortunio) though all the world knows he was born a foetus, (Ce Foetus n'étoit pas plus grand que la paume de la main; mais son père l'ayant examiné en qualité de Médecin, \& ayant trouvé que c'étoit quelque chose de plus qu'un Embryon, le fit transporter tout vivant à Rapallo, où il le fit voir à Jérôme Bardi \& à d'autres Médecins du lieu. On trouva qu'il ne lui manquoit rien d'essentiel à la vie; \& son père pour faire voir un essai de son expérience, entreprit d'achever l'ouvrage de la Nature, \& de travailler à la formation de l'Enfant avec le même artifice que celui dont on se sert pour faire ecclorre les Poulets en Egypte. Il instruisit une Nourisse de tout ce qu'elle avoit à faire, \& ayant fait mettre son fils dans un pour proprement accommode, il réussit a l'élever \& à lui faire prendre ses accroissemens nécessaires, par l'uniformité d'une chaleur étrangère mesurée exactement sur les degrés d'un Thermomètre, ou d'un autre instrument équivalent. (Vide Mich. Giustinian, ne gli Scritt. Liguri a 223. 488.) On auroit toujours été très satisfait de l'industrie d'un père si expérimenté dans l'Art de la Génération, quand il n'auroit pu prolonger la vie à son fils que pour quelques mois, ou pour peu d'années. Mais quand on se représente que l'Enfant a vécu près de quatre-vingts ans, \& qu'il a composé quatre-vingts Ouvrages différents tous fruits d'une longue lecture---il faut convenir que tout ce qui est incroyable n'est pas toujours faux, \& que la Vraisemblance n'est pas toujours du côté de la Vérité. Il n'avoit que dix neuf ans lorsqu'il composa \emph{Gonopsychanthropologia de Origine Animae humanae}. (Les Enfans célèbres, revus \& corrigés par M. de la Monnoye de l'Académie Francoise.)) of no more than five inches and a half in length, yet he grew to that astonishing height in literature, as to write a book with a title as long as himself---the learned know I mean his Gonopsychanthropologia, upon the origin of the human soul.

So much for my chapter upon chapters, which I hold to be the best chapter in my whole work; and take my word, whoever reads it, is full as
well employed, as in picking straws.

\end{document}
```

[image]